# C++ Forward declaration and files design

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

I've read lots of articles about forward declaration, but I still have a question.
Let's suppose we have:

```
// File a.hpp (in this question I avoid writing guards in header files, for the sake of simplicity)

class A
{
    // Class B is used only by pointer, the compiler doesn't need to know the structure
    // of the class, so a forward declaration is enough
    public:
        A(void);
        void Method1(B *pB);
        void Method2(B *pB);           
};

// File a.cpp

#include "a.hpp"

A::A(void) { }

// Some methods of class B are used, so the compiler needs to know the declaration of the class, it cannot be forward declared

void A::Method1(B *pB)
{
    // Something...
    pB->SomeMethod();
    // Something ...
}

void A::Method2(B *pB)
{
    int var = pB->GetSomeMember();
    // Something ...
}
```

Ok, now let's suppose to have one header file for class B declaration and another one for its forward declaration:

```
// File b.hpp

// Class declaration
class B
{ 
/* ... */
};

// File b_fwd.hpp

// Forward declaration
class B;
```

What I have in mind, basing on the previous considerations, is to include "b_fwd.hpp" in a.hpp (which only needs the forward declaration of class B), and "b.hpp" in the a.cpp file (which need the declaration),
as follows:

```
// File a.hpp

#include "b_fwd.hpp"  // Forward declaration of class B

class A
{
    public:
        A(void);
        void Method1(B *pB);
        void Method2(B *pB);           
};

// File a.cpp

#include "a.hpp"
#include "b.hpp"  // Declaration of class B

A::A(void) { }

void A::Method1(B *pB) { /* like before ... */ }

void A::Method2(B *pB) { /* like before ... */ }
```

I know this works, but since in class A I included (let's say) "twice" the class B, the first time forward declared and the second time "normally", this sounds a little strange to me. I want to know if this is a good practise, and if it can be done or not in projects.

Comment: Why not simply forward declare `class B` in `a.hpp` ? What do you think putting it in a separate header achieves ? Do note that the `#include "some_file"` directive basically makes the preprocessor copy the content of `some_file` in the file that has the directive before the compilation phase.

Comment: I know, but I prefer to "encapsulate" it into the .hpp file. For instance, if there are namespaces or templates, I don't want to write them each time with the risk of errors and problems for making future changes, but I wirte only once in the .hpp file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use this technique often with great success.

And to answer the question "why not just forward declare it?" sometimes it is difficult to forward declare.  For example if a class is a template class the forward declaration must include the template parameters as well as the class name.

Comment: Hmm, I doubt that this is useful! I'd follow @JBL's suggestion. At least when a user needs to use the class he should be familiar with all the template parameters provided, and should be able to write an appropriate forward class declaration.

Comment: If you plan to USE it, then sure you should know the details, you get those by including the main header file for the class.   If you plan to pass a reference or pointer to it as a parameter, then replicating the template parameters in a multitude of other header files is a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: _'Maintenance'_ That's an argument, yes!